# incircle tanget to triangle at D and incirles of ADC ADB

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles, tangent-line

$ABC$ is a triangle the circle is tangent to $BC$ at $D$ prove that 
the incircles of $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle ACD$ are tangent to each other.

[image]

What i tried is calling the smaller incircles tangent to 
$AC$ and $AB$ at $E$ and $F$, respectively. 
Then i need to prove $AE=AF$.

Comment: Could You put the original wordings here and is there any picture?

Answer (score 1):

Let touch-points of the incircles of $\Delta ACD$ and $\Delta ADB$ to $AD$ be $P$ and $Q$ respectively.

Thus, in the standard notation we obtain:
$$DP=\frac{AD+CD-AC}{2}=\frac{AD+\frac{a+b-c}{2}-b}{2}=\frac{AD+\frac{a+c-b}{2}-c}{2}=DQ$$ and we are done!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Repeatedly use that the distances from any point to the two tangent points of a circle is equal,

$$\begin{array} 
AAE - AF & = (AY+YE)-(AX+XF) \\
& =YE - XF\\
& = (CY - CE) - (BX - BF) \\
& = (CD - CP) - (BD - BQ) \\
& = DP - DQ \\
& = DT - DT = 0 \\
\end{array}$$